# Need help Sorting an Array Via Pointers

Tags: c++, sorting

So I need to have a Dynamic Array sorted by reference via Pointers.

The user inputs an indeterminate amount of grades which s/he states as the end, the inputs the grades manually.

I need to sort those grades in ascending order, I feel as if I am very close, although my output is giving me really random numbers and I don't know the cause, and I can't really change anything because I think i'm on the right track but I can't figure out these random numbers in the output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
    void swap (int *num1, int *num2)
{
int temp = *num1;
*num1=*num2;
*num2 = temp;
}

void Order(int Gnum[], int Gtot)
{
for (int i = 0; i < Gtot; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < Gtot; j++)
        if (Gnum[i] > Gnum[j])
        {
            swap(Gnum[i], Gnum[j]);

        }
    cout << Gnum[i];
}

}
int main() {

int input;
int input2;

cout << "Please input number of Grades" << endl;
cin >> input2;
cout << "Please input Grades" << endl;
cin >> input;
for (int i = 1; i < input2; i++)
{
    cin >> input;
}

Order(&input, input2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: please tag all homework question as C.

Comment: Your sorting procedure is wrong, and you are printing your numbers before the sorting procedure is complete.

Comment: Are you required to use native arrays, and your own sort and swap? Or can you use the STL?

Comment: Actually, `Order` is the only *correct* bit of code.

Comment: I have to make my own sort and swap, I just got rid of the swap and put it inthe second for loop anyway in the Order function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the running version of your code, see the different for yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
void swap (int *num1, int *num2)
{
    int temp = *num1;
    *num1=*num2;
    *num2 = temp;
}

void Order(int Gnum[], int Gtot)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Gtot; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < Gtot; j++)
        if (Gnum[i] > Gnum[j])
        {
            swap(&Gnum[i], &Gnum[j]);

        }
        cout << Gnum[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {

    int *input;
    int input2;

    cout << "Please input number of Grades" << endl;

    cin >> input2;
    input = new int[input2];

    for (int i = 0; i < input2; i++)
    {
        cout << "please input grade " << i << ": ";
        cin >> input[i];
    }

    Order(input, input2);
    delete [] input;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I saw what I did wrong, I didn't fully grasp the concept of the input = new int[input2]; line.

But I think with what you did I am able to understand a lot better on where I was pretty off the mark. Thank you so much.

Comment: "input = new int[input2];" line allocates a dynamic memory of "input2" numbers of int in heap memory and saves that memory location to "input" pointer. You can read more about dynamic memory allocation at this link: [Dynamic Memory](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

Answer (score 0):

First off, swap won't help you order the pointer array. second I would, in your order function create a pointer array of the same size as your initial array and then perform the following inside void Order(////):

```
for (int i = 0; i < initArraySize; ++i){
   int index = 0;
   int lowest = initArr[0];
   for (int j = 0; j < initArraySize; ++j){
       if (lowest > initArr[i]){
          lowest = initArr[i];
          index = i;
       }
   }
   newArr[0] = lowest;
   initArr[index] = 100000; //so that this won't be looked at again
}

delete [] initArr;

initArr = newArr;
```